# Group cohomology of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $K$ be a field not isomorphic to $\mathbb F_2$, $V = K^n$ - vector space over $K$ on which $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ acts. How to compute cohomology groups $H^i(\mathrm{GL}(V),V)$? It is easy to see that $H^0(\mathrm{GL}(V),V) = 0$ but what about other cohomology groups?